# How to set windows batch variable based on which version of windows the batch file is running in?

Tags: windows, batch-file

**Scenario**

Let us assume an application is installed on Windows XP, and on Windows 7, for a single user and that it installs to the following directories in these 2 operating systems:

Windows XP:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<user_name>\Local Settings\Application Data\<target-folder>
```

Windows 7:

```
C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\<target-folder>
```

I want to create a batch script that will assign the target-folder directory to a variable within the script.

**Question**

What is the simplest and most robust way to set a variable in a batch script based on which version of windows the script is running in?

**Example Answer**

```
set targetDir = ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research I found this [resource](http://malektips.com/xp_dos_0025p.html) to be both simple and robust because it detects all versions of Windows rather than just windows xp or windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

```
ver | find "XP" >nul && (
    set "TargetDir=%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\[target-folder]"
) || (
    set "TargetDir=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\[target-folder]"
)
echo "%TargetDir%"
```

Comment: That is atleast simple, if not very robust.

Answer (score 1):

There is a environment variable named **%USERPROFILE%** or **%APPDATA%** which can be used to query the profile path name.

In general use **WMIC** for to query info like this, it works in XP (Professional but not home), Vista, windows 7, windows 8, and servers. For example to get the OS name use:

```
WMIC OS GET caption
```

Or name instead of caption if you want more info. You can ask for other data such as OSArchitecture that would tell you if its 32 or 64 bit. And you can combine queries, like this:

```
WMIC OS GET caption, osarchitecture, muilanguages
```

You can get full list with WMIC OS but read the docs on WMIC it can do a lot of different queries and tasks, such as listing all users. But the real catch is that you can query OTHER users environments with:

```
wmic ENVIRONMENT
:: and
wmic /user user ENVIRONMENT
```

Last but not least, if even version fails to give you a clue you can use

```
IF EXISTS C:\Users
```

To determine if folders exist.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is, "it depends".

For example, I control the computer setups at work and our Windows 7 machines are all 64-bit, so I can check for `C:\Program Files (x86)`.

So, I do something like this:

```
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" (
  SET TargetDir=C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\<target-folder>
) ELSE (
  SET TargetDir=C:\Documents and Settings\<user_name>\<target-folder>
)
```

Granted, these are not foolproof, but they work for my needs.

If you are talking about computers that you don't control or use a different language, then things get more complicated.

Comment: heuristically trying to 'figure out' what OS you are on is, like you said, fraught with peril.  Endoro's solution seems like it would be a much more robust way of determining if you're on XP or not

Comment: I think you missed the button.  :)